# Is there a way to sync with a remote folder over SFTP?

Tags: sftp

The remote folder in question does not have a shell or allows ssh connections, nor it has a ftp server. The folder to be sync is big, with hundreds of files and continuously updated, and I need some way of downloading any new or modified files quickly.

I have tried lftp and rsync, but the connection is not allowed. I thought about writing a script over sftp, but it seems too complex and slow. I could also use Python, but from what I know the script would be similar.

I would like to install only well-known libraries, if any, but I am not sure about my options here.

Comment: You probably get better answer on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: If you want to help with coding this in some *specific* language, we can help you. But if you are looking for a software, then you need to ask elsewhere, like at [softwarerecs.se]. + Knowing your local platform would also be relevant. + Btw, lftp should be able to sync over SFTP.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl You are right. I used sftp:// prefix on lftp address and it worked. It was connection to ftp by default and I did not think that it was necessary to specify the protocol. Many thanks!